# "out of" vs. "among" vs. "from"

Tags: prepositions

Which of the following sentences is the most idiomatic?

"I can't choose just one necklace out of so many beautiful necklaces."

"I can't choose just one necklace among so many beautiful necklaces."

"I can't choose just one necklace from so many beautiful necklaces."

Answer (score 2):

When you [choose one](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/choose), we perceive it as taking one thing out from among several others. It therefore works with **out of** or **from**, but does not work with **among** on its own. You can use **from among** instead though.

This [ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=choose%20one%20from%20among%2C%20choose%20one%20from%2C%20choose%20one%20out%20of&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cchoose%20one%20from%20among%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cchoose%20one%20from%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cchoose%20one%20out%20of%3B%2Cc0) gives a rough idea of the relative popularities.